# INSERT multi rows using something like sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.TYPES WHERE NAME = 'TestTableType')
    DROP TYPE TestTableType

CREATE TYPE TestTableType AS TABLE (ID INT)
GO

DECLARE @T TestTableType
INSERT @T SELECT 6*7
INSERT @T SELECT 4*7
INSERT @T SELECT 8

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * from @var', N'@var TestTableType READONLY', @t
GO
```

This code returns:

```
42
28
8
```

If it were allowed, this what I'd like to do:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT @var    SELECT * from @var', N'@var TestTableType READONLY', @t
```

That is re-inserting the 3 rows into table variable `@t`. But it must be READONLY and, of course, won't work.

Does anyone know a workaround or alternate option for SQL Server 2008 Standard?

Thanks 
Padraig

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions#Restrictions) there is no way to do this with Table-Valued Parameters.

You could consider writing the values to a ##temp table which is then accessible from the next statement.

Comment: This kind of works:
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.TYPES WHERE NAME = 'TestTableType') 
DROP TYPE TestTableType 
CREATE TYPE TestTableType AS TABLE (ID INT) 
GO 
DECLARE @T TestTableType 
INSERT @T SELECT 6*7 
INSERT @T SELECT 4*7 
INSERT @T SELECT 8 
INSERT @T
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * from @var', N'@var TestTableType READONLY', @t 
SELECT * FROM @T